# What is the best way to report scam/fraud token

Tags: tokens

Recently I've bought small amount of some token with good overall idea as it seems for the first look. Then I go deeper to the source code and found that product is fraudulent, with differences between written in the whitepaper and actual product implementation.

How can I complain about token effectively? Want others to not repeat my mistakes

Comment: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqjDY.png) I never requested to delete account . Do they send emails like this

Answer (score 4):

This topic is kindof interesting. There are a few things you can do:

**Report the token on etherscan:**

In my opinion this is probably the most effective thing you can do.
Go to etherscan.io/dapp/0xScamTokenAddress
On the bottom of the left sidebar you will find a "Report Button".

**Write a blog post:**

If you don't have a blog this solution is probably not the right for you.
However, you can write to popular influencers/news sites in the crypto space and ask them to cover your token. (This only makes sense if you token is somewhat popular)

**Warn users in the scam tokens telegram group:**

This one is not that effective as you are only telling your information to people that probably already own the token. Nonetheless it is a good try.

**Write the scam token company:**

Maybe writing them an email and asking them for why they did something.

**Report it:**

In case it is something major you can report it to local authorities.

**Ensure that your problem is so important:**

Are you really sure that the problem you specifically are mentioning is so severe? Even though something is stated in the whitepaper companies might find better solutions to some problem and take these instead.

I am a programmer myself and things often turn out completely different than planned. Resulting in me changing my plans and adapting to the new problems. Finding solutions to them might change my plans for already implemented function and algorithms.

This happens all the time. However it is important to officially state that adjustments were made. You should probably take a look if your company has made an officall press release stating why they made changes to their plan.

If they did and they are reasonable (and don't change the core concept of the project) they are completely fine in my opinion.

I hope my short explanation helped you.

Answer (score 4):

Report scam domains and addresses to https://cryptoscamdb.org/

If a scam is impersonating another project, let that project know.

Comment: Also you can report the website for phishing at Google https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=en as a mob

Answer (score 2):

Report Scam tokens to DappRadar repository:
https://github.com/dappradar/tokens-blacklist